# Need to iterate an xml with child nodes with same name

Tags: java, xml, nodes

I have an `xml`

```
<CommonTestData>
<GiftCards> 
  <GiftCard>
      <cardnumber>7777016774730834</cardnumber>
      <number>1815</number>
  </GiftCard>
  <GiftCard>
      <cardnumber>7777016774687937</cardnumber>
      <number>6256</number>
  </GiftCard>
</GiftCards>
```

I have to iterate these xml and read values and enter into an `Selenium` web application and check whether gift card applied amount is greater than zero . `If the amount applied is zero then try another card . If the amount applied is greater than zero then break the loop`

My code something look like

```
for (int i=0;i<xmlvalue.getNodeCount("GiftCard", "CommonTestData.xml");i++){
            //giftcardaccordian.click();
            giftcardnumber.sendKeys(xmlvalue.getValue("cardnumber"+i, "GiftCard", "CommonTestData.xml")); // I need code for getvalue function so that i can iterate through 
            giftcardpin.sendKeys(xmlvalue.getValue("cardnumber"+i, "GiftCard", "CommonTestData.xml"));

            giftcardapplybutton.click();
            try{
                if(appliedgiftcardamount.getText()!="$0"){
                    break;
                }
            }catch (Exception e ){
                Assert.fail("Cannot apply reward certicate");
            }
        }
```

I need implementaion for Getvalue so that i can iterate through. Right now my implementation is something like

```
public String getValue(String csstagname, String Elementname, String xmlfilename) {
    String eElement1;

    try {
      String path = "config/XML/" + xmlfilename;
      File fXmlFile = new File(path);
      DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
      DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
      Document doc = dBuilder.parse(fXmlFile);
      doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
      NodeList nList = doc.getElementsByTagName(Elementname);

      for (int temp = 0; temp < nList.getLength(); temp++) {

        Node nNode = nList.item(temp);
        if (nNode.getNodeType() == Node.ELEMENT_NODE) {
          eElement1 = csstagname;
          Element eElement2 = (Element) nNode;

          value = (getTagValue(eElement1, eElement2));

        }
      }
    } catch (Exception e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {

      return (value);
    }
  }
```

Comment: Your question doesn't really have anything to do with Selenium. You should remove that tag.

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is possible, but it's not in the spirit of XML. Do you control the XML file? Change the format so that card nnumber and number have their own overarching tag to bind them together:

```
<CommonTestData>
    <GiftCards> 
      <GiftCard>
          <cardnumber>7777016774730834</cardnumber>
          <number>1815</number>
      </GiftCard>
      <GiftCard>
          <cardnumber>7777016774687937</cardnumber>
          <number>6256</number>
      </GiftCard>
    </GiftCards>
</CommonTestData>
```

If you do not control the format, extract all nodes tagged with `cardnumber`, all nodes tagged with `number`, then access both arrays with same index.

Comment: Yes I can change the XML format. Yes this one I will change this, looks good